# External DNS resolution not consistent in AWS VPC

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have 2 instances in a VPC. The VPC is set up with the correct DHCP option set to enable public DNS resolution. Both instances are identical, and are launched using the same bootstrap scripts and orchestration workflow.

`ins1`:
`dig quay.io in A` returns the A records for quay.io.

`ins2`: `dig quay.io in A` returns NXDOMAIN.

Other domains that I try to `dig` on ins2 seem to resolve correctly, but I can no longer be sure of the reliability of the VPC-provided DNS, as quay.io is the domain i really need to be able to resolve.

I launched `ins3` that is identical to `ins2` and `ins1`. DNS resolution seems to be working fine on `ins3`.

All 3 instances are in different subnets and different availability zones. I have not yet tried launching another instance into the same subnet/AZ as `ins2`, but the subnets are set up identically, so this might be a red herring.

Anyone ever run into this?

Comment: an update: DNS resolution started working eventually on `ins2`. It took about half an hour to correct itself.

Is this something I should be concerned about, and/or engage AWS support? Or is there a reason for this that should be mitigated against?

Comment: What was the negative TTL of the record? Each subnet can have it's own DNS resolver - so if the resolver from ins2 already had a negative answer it will save this answer for a period of time (maybe 30 minutes in your case). All other resolver could send a different answer then for this timeframe.

Comment: That is a good point, I did not record the TTL so can't really say, but I do know that both instances were using the same resolver, I specifically checked for that.